# char pointer array out put is difference c++

Tags: c++

while i tried some sample program in c++ using char* array, the output from the program is not very clear to me.

sample code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string val="val1";
    char* hello[10]={NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL};

    hello[1]=(char*)val.c_str();

    val="val2";

    printf("The val in hello[1] is :%s\n",hello[1]);

    hello[3]=(char*)val.c_str();

    printf("The val in hello[3] is :%s\n",hello[3]);
}
```

Result :

```
The val in hello[1] is :val2

The val in hello[3] is :val2
```

But same program i was append the string

```
val.append("val2"); //val="val2";
```

The result is

```
The val in hello[1] is :val1

The val in hello[3] is :val1val2
```

can you kindly explain, how the output is giving 2 different results?

Comment: Notice that `NULL` is not a `char` value.

Comment: Do you understand that append "adds" the string after the string that is already assigned? In the comment it seems not...

Comment: There's a reason your compiler doesn't accept those assignments without casts. That doesn't mean cast it, it means store `const char *` (and watch that they don't become invalidated).

Comment: In first case when I have assigned val=val1 and assigning the value to hello[1] and again assigning new value to val as val2.When I tried to print hello[1] it printing val2 instead of val1,In second case i have assigned val=val1 and assigning hell0[1]=val, then again append new value in val.append("val2"), then it showing my expected output in hello[1] variable, my query is that why hello[1] is two different output. i.e val2 in first case and val1 in second case.

Comment: The pointer returned by `c_str()` can be invalidated by calling a non-const member function, like `append()`. Saving that pointer and then modifying the `std::string` is a bad idea and obviously error-prone.

Comment: same thing with many containers in C++. After doing write operation, the original pointer/iterator may be invalid because of reallocation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string.c_str()` returns the internal `char*` buffer used by the `string`.

When you first get a pointer to the internal buffer via `c_str()` and store it in `hello[1]`, the buffer contains `"val1"`. On the next line you overwrite the string with the value `"val2"`. Since `"val1"` and `"val2"` are the same length, the new value fits in the original buffer, so it's overwritten.

In contrast, when you append `"val2"` to `val`, the original internal buffer must be too small to hold the result, so it allocates a new one. Hence, `hello[1]` and `hello[3]` point to two different `char*`s, and they hold different values.

You can see that the two printers are not equal by adding a couple of lines to the end of your program:

```
printf("Pointer in hello[1]: %p\n", hello[1]);
printf("Pointer in hello[3]: %p\n", hello[3]);
```

I got these results on a test run:

```
Pointer in hello[1]: 0x10ca00a68
Pointer in hello[3]: 0x10ca00a88
```

Calling `append` obviously forced the string to allocate a new, larger buffer. However, you're not guaranteed that the buffer in `hello[1]` will maintain its current value, because the `string` implementation might decide to reuse that buffer later if you make another call to a string method—maybe even on another string.

Answer (score 1):

In first case you are assigning the values to the std::string explicitely, wiping the previous value stored there, but in second case with std::string::append you are adding new value "val2" to previously existed one "val1".

Here is some specs: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append
"Extends the string by appending additional characters at the end of its current value"

Answer (score 0):

An array of type char* with all NULLs will be treated by c++ as an empty string.

What happens: printf receives a pointer in memory and starts to 'print' characters one by one until it encounters NULL. So NULL terminates string. Everything after NULL is never taken into account

append() in this case will start placing characters at the end of previous character. Which is the first NULL after the "val1"

Hope it helps